# How do you update a many to many field from a form?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the following two models:

```
class TaskFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='task-files/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name

class Task(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ManyToManyField(TaskFile, related_name='task_files')
```

I have a model form to update the Task object that is already created, but the many to many relationships do not show up in the form. It just shows the option to upload a file and does not show the existing files in that object.

How can I fix this?

Edit:

This is my model form code:

```
class TutorTaskSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lesson = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('lesson')
```

This is my template:

```
<form action="{{request.path}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {%csrf_token%}
  <div class="box-body">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number</label>

       <div class="col-sm-10">
         {{form.lesson}}
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Please show us your `modelform code` and how you render it in your `template`.

Comment: I've added my model form and template

Comment: As i understand, you want to save multiple files to lesson field, right?

Comment: Yes, I need to save multiple files to it. Is there many to many field the best way to do it?

Comment: Well, i wouldn't do that with this way. I am going to write a detailed answer now below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i am not a huge fan of built-in `Django Forms`. So i am going to suggest you a different way. A way without `Django Forms`.

*Out of context of this question:*

> There are great, i mean really great, front-end libraries like
>   `React`, `Vue` or `Angular`. And they are getting more popular every
>   day, or even every minute. When you decide to choose one of those
>   fancy libraries, using Django forms doesn't make sense so much.

Anyway, If you want to keep your existing model structure, I think the best thing you can do here is updating the logic inside of your view:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.FILES.getlist)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('lesson')

        # @TODO: check if form is valid or files are proper etc. here

        task = Task() # new task instance here
        task.save()

        for f in files:
            task_file = TaskFile()
            task_file.file = f
            task_file.save() # save uploaded file to the TaskFile

            task.lesson.add(task_file) #  here add that file to the many to many field of Task Model

        return HttpResponse('All files saved!')
    else:
        ctx = {
            'form': TutorTaskSelectForm()
        }
        return render(request, 'index.html', ctx)
```

I tested above code. It is working. But you must clarify what you mean by saying `uploading multiple files`.

Do you want to select multiple files at once? Or do you want different and separate file dialog boxes for each file?

If you want to have `multiple selection` while picking files from browser dialog box, then above solution should work for you.

But If you want to have multiple files by picking them separately, then you need multiple `inputs` in your html side. Something like this:

```
<form action="{{ request.path }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="lesson" required />
    <input type="file" name="lesson" required />
    <input type="file" name="lesson" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Note that you don't need Django forms in this case. Just create regular input files then handle them in you view. You can reach files inside a request by calling `request.FILES.getlist('lesson')`.

But again, i wouldn't use django forms for this case. Here is the version of not using django forms:

```
<form action="{{request.path}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="file" name="lesson" required multiple />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Put those lines in your html, and use the code above. This is very basic and simple. You can update it according to your requirements.